# numpy around/rint slow compared to astype(int)

Tags: python, c, assembly, numpy, sse

So if I have something like `x=np.random.rand(60000)*400-200`. iPython's `%timeit` says:

- `x.astype(int)` takes 0.14ms
- `np.rint(x)` and `np.around(x)` take 1.01ms

Note that in the `rint` and `around` cases you still need to spend the extra 0.14ms to do a final `astype(int)` (assuming that's what you ultimately want).

**Question:** am I right in thinking that most modern hardware is capable of doing both operations in equal time. If so, why is numpy taking 8 times longer for the rounding?

As it happens I'm not super fussy about the exactness of the arithmetic, but I can't see how to take advantage of that with numpy (I'm doing messy biology not particle physics).

Comment: Admitting that I am not that much familiar with arithmetic capabilities of CPUs: Why would they be able to do it in equal time? astype is just cutting away a few bits, rounding operations require to check how much it is you cut away (to determine if you round to the lower or higher int).

Comment: Well, one thing is that casting to integer type from a float involves simply discarding the fractional part, which is equivalent to rounding towards zero, while `np.rint` rounds to the *nearest* integer (which is extra work). Therefore, `np.trunc` is more comparable to `np.astype(int)`. In my speedtests, `np.trunc` is still slower, but looking at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a32a9327b433ec47051b16a1a87190f640e8475d/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c.src), this is probably because it is implemented in terms of ceil and floor, and not a simple cast.

Comment: There seem to be low level flags to control rounding mode, see for example: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath.

Answer (score 10):

`np.around(x).astype(int)` and `x.astype(int)` don't produce the same values. The former rounds even (it's the same as `((x*x>=0+0.5) + (x*x<0-0.5)).astype(int)`) whereas the latter rounds towards zero. However,

```
y = np.trunc(x).astype(int)
z = x.astype(int)
```

shows `y==z` but calculating `y` is much slower. So it's the `np.trunc`and `np.around` functions which are slow.

```
In [165]: x.dtype
Out[165]: dtype('float64')
In [168]: y.dtype
Out[168]: dtype('int64')
```

So `np.trunc(x)` rounds towards zero from double to double. Then `astype(int)` has to convert double to int64.

Internally I don't know what python or numpy are doing but I know how I would do this in C. Let's discuss some hardware. With SSE4.1 it's possible to do round, floor, ceil, and trunc from double to double using:

```
_mm_round_pd(a, 0); //round: round even
_mm_round_pd(a, 1); //floor: round towards minus infinity
_mm_round_pd(a, 2); //ceil:  round towards positive infinity
_mm_round_pd(a, 3); //trunc: round towards zero
```

but numpy needs to support systems without SSE4.1 as well so it would have to build without SSE4.1 as well as with SSE4.1 and then use a dispatcher.

But to do this from double directly to int64 using SSE/AVX is not efficient until AVX512. However, it is possible to round double to int32 efficiently using only SSE2:

```
_mm_cvtpd_epi32(a);  //round double to int32 then expand to int64
_mm_cvttpd_epi32(a); //trunc double to int32 then expand to int64
```

These converts two doubles to two int64.

In your case this would work fine since the range is certainly within int32. But unless python knows the range fits in int32 it can't assume this so it would have to round or trunc to int64 which is slow. Also, once again numpy would have to build to support SSE2 to do this anyway.

But maybe you could have used a single floating point array to begin with. In that case you could have done:

```
_mm_cvtps_epi32(a); //round single to int32
_mm_cvttps_epi32(a) //trunc single to int32
```

These convert four singles to four int32.

So to answer your question SSE2 can round or truncated from double to int32 efficiently. AVX512 will be able to round or truncated from double to int64 efficiently as well using `_mm512_cvtpd_epi64(a)` or `_mm512_cvttpd_epi64(a)`.  SSE4.1 can round/trunc/floor/ceil from float to float or double to double efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I have just tried making ``x`` single and using ``int32`` instead of ``int``...but no luck. Also I noticed that ``rint`` has an ``out`` arg which you can set to an empty ``int32`` array, but that too is no help with speed.
(I cant work out which SSE version my numpy has been compiled with, but it's likely to be SSE2 or SSE3 as it's a decent enough machine and the windows installer is supposed to have no-SSE,SSE2 and SSE3 binaries.)

Comment: @dan-man, yeah, I tried np.float32 and np.int32 and other variations but no improvement. But is this really a problem for you? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". This is something the numpy developers should worry about.

Comment: I was hoping a numpy developer would appear and tell me a quick hack or point me to a known bug...if so that would have been worth it because I have a function that spends 1 second (>50% total time) on ``rint``, and I need to call that function hundreds of times.  But yes, I probably should admit to a degree of premature optimization. (Although, when I spotted this discrepancy, it occurred to me that there may be a whole class of such things where numpy is an order of magnitude slower than it ought to be..if so, it is worth knowing about them.)

Comment: @dan-man, in that case, you may want to post your function on SO and see what answers you get. I generally optimize in C. Some of us at work also use pyopencl. You might want to consider that. I used that in the past but I can good enough results with the OpenMP and SIMD on the CPU now in C.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @jme in the comments, the `rint` and `around` functions must work out whether to round the fractions up or down to the nearest integer. In contrast, the `astype` function will always round down so it can immediately discard the decimal information. There are a number of other functions that do the same thing. Also, you could improve the speed by using a lower number of bits for the integer. However you must be careful that you can accommodate the full range of your input data.

```
%%timeit
np.int8(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 µs per loop
```

Note, this does not store values outside the range -128 to 127 as it's 8-bit. Some values in your example fall outside this range.

Of all the others I tried, `np.intc` seems to be the fastest:

```
%%timeit
np.int16(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 186 µs per loop

%%timeit
np.intc(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop

%%timeit
np.int0(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 µs per loop

%%timeit
np.int_(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 188 µs per loop

%%timeit
np.int32(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop

%%timeit
    np.trunc(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 940 µs per loop
```

Your examples, on my machine:

```
%%timeit
np.around(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

%%timeit
np.rint(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

%%timeit
x.astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 188 µs per loop
```