# Numpy rounding performance

Tags: python, performance, numpy, types, rounding

I am seeing some very surprising behaviour from numpy (version 1.10.4). See the following code with output:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand()
b = np.random.rand(1)[0]
print('a: ',a)
print('b:', b)
print('type(a): ', type(a))
print('type(a): ', type(b))
print('round(a):', round(a))
print('round(b):', round(b))
print('\n')

%timeit round(a)
%timeit round(b)
%timeit int(round(b))



a:  0.4991662851604657
b: 0.301059130742
type(a):  <class 'float'>
type(a):  <class 'numpy.float64'>
round(a): 0
round(b): 0.0


The slowest run took 7.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 232 ns per loop
The slowest run took 13.84 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 µs per loop
The slowest run took 6.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 µs per loop
```

`np.random.rand` seems to return different numerical types in two very similar cases.

This bit me, since I started to rely on the behaviour of Python's `round` which returns an `int` by default. If, however, the input to `round` is a `numpy.float64` it returns a `float`, I guess because `numpy.round` does. Relying on the behaviour of `round` suddenly becomes quite dangerous.

The performance of `round` on `float` vs `numpy.float64` is also dramatically different, so much so that it had an appreciable impact on my library.

Is the performance issue a bug, or is numpy overhead really *that* dramatic, even for scalar `floats`, or are there issues with the way benchmarking works here? How can I get fast rounding to `int` performance from `numpy.float64`s?

Finally, why does `rand()` return a different type than `rand(1)[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

`round(a)` actually calls `a.__round__()`, which is presumably implemented differently for python `float` and `np.float`. Due to different applications, developers must have chosen different return types for each of the returns of `__round__`.

I am afraid that there is not a reliable universal way to extend `numpy` performance to python native types. You can investigate `numba` package for `jit` functionality.

Edit:

Regarding your last question, my guess is that `np.rand` returns a `float` as an optimization in order to avoid boxing it in an `array` when you only need one random number.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to extend native performance to numpy, not the other way around. I was expecting numpy to _outperform_ native Python, hence my surprise.

Numba is a good idea, though. Interestingly, defining my own method which simply calls `round`, with a `@jit` decoration, regains performance, _and_ also returns an `int`, even on `numpy.float64`s. Do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252209/numpy-around-rint-slow-compared-to-astypeint In short, you can use `np.intc` to round, but make sure it behaves as you want it to. Regarding `numba` type conversion, I am not sure, but I think it would make a great question of its own.

Comment: Interesting. However, `np.intc` appears to truncate rather than round. Furthermore, its performance on native `float`s is only half as good as native `round`, and twice as slow as that again on `numpy.float64`s.